# How to return early in a pattern match of akka actor receive

Tags: scala, syntax, akka, partialfunction

Tried googling variations on this trivial question but didn't get an answer...

Basically I have a pattern match in my receive method. 
In some cases I want to break early from the receive handling

```
    override def receive = {
        case blah => {
          ... preflight code
          if (preflight failed) {
            sender() ! errorMSG 
            "break" or "return" here // get error "method receive has a return statement ; needs result type - 
// I tried adding Unit to the receive and return statements
          }
          ... more code
           ....

          if (something happened) {
            sender() ! anotherErrorMSG
            "break" or "return" here
          }
          ...
       }
       case foo => {...}
       case bar => {...}
     } // end receive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this discussion of return's semantics](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html) and remember that receive returns a PartialFunction[Any, Unit] which is then evaluated after receive has returned.  In short, there's no way to return early.

Ömer Erden's solution of throwing an exception and using actor supervision works (indeed, exception throwing with all of its overhead is basically the only way to reliably end a computation early), but if you need any state to carry over from message to message, you'll need Akka persistence.

If you don't want to nest if-elses as in chunjef's solution, you can use context.become and stash to create some spaghetti-ish code.

But the best solution may be to have the things that might fail be their own functions with Either result types.  Note that the Either API in scala 2.12 is quite a bit nicer than in previous versions.

```
import scala.util.{ Either, Left, Right }

type ErrorMsg = ...
type PreflightSuccess = ... // contains anything created in preflight that you need later
type MoreCodeSuccess = ... // contains anything created in preflight or morecode that you need later

def preflight(...): Either[ErrorMsg, PreFlightSuccess] = {
  ... // preflight
  if (preflight failed)
    Left(errorMsg)
  else
    Right(...) // create a PreflightSuccess
}

def moreCode1(pfs: PreFlightSuccess): Either[ErrorMsg, MoreCodeSuccess] = {
  ... // more code
  if (something happened)
    Left(anotherErrorMSG)
  else
    Right(...) // create a MoreCodeSuccess
}

def moreCode2(mcs: MoreCodeSuccess): Either[ErrorMsg, Any] = {
  ... // more code, presumably never fails
  Right(...)
}

override def receive = {
  case blah =>
    val pf = preflight(...)
    val result = pf.map(morecode1).joinRight.map(moreCode2).joinRight // only calls morecode1 if preflight succeeded, and only calls morecode2 if preflight and morecode1 succeeded
    result.fold(
      { errorMsg => sender ! errorMsg },
      ()
    )
  case foo => ...
  case bar => ...
}
```

Whether this is preferable to nested if-else's is a question of taste...

Comment: You could also replace map(...).joinRight with flatMap(...), now that I look at it.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your question's exact answer but in your case adding [supervisor](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/scala/general/supervision.html#what-supervision-means) actor would be the better solution. In Akka Supervision model convince you to handle exceptions on supervisor actor instead of sending error messages back to the sender.

This approach brings you a fault-tolerant model and also **you can throw exception** at any line you want(which solves your current problem), your supervisor actor will handle the throwable with restarting, resuming or stopping the child actor.

please check the [link](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/fault-tolerance.html)